# PostgreSQL INSERT INTO within Function

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

I got the tables:

General

```
CREATE TABLE general
(
  equipo character varying(30) NOT NULL,
  partidos_jug integer,
  partidos_gana integer,
  partidos_emp integer,
  partidos_perd integer,
  puntos integer,
  goles_favor integer,
  CONSTRAINT general_pkey PRIMARY KEY (equipo)
)
```

Equipos

```
create table equipos
(num_eqpo serial,     
ciudad varchar (30),
num_gpo int, 
nom_equipo varchar (30), 
primary key (num_eqpo), 
foreign key (num_gpo) references grupos (num_gpo))
```

Partidos

```
create table partidos 
(semana int, 
num_eqpo_loc int, 
num_eqpo_vis int, 
goles_loc int, 
goles_vis int, primary key (semana,num_eqpo_loc,num_eqpo_vis), 
foreign key (num_eqpo_loc) references equipos (num_eqpo), 
foreign key (num_eqpo_vis) references equipos (num_eqpo))
```

I want to copy certain data from the table Equipos to the table General using:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sp_tablageneral () RETURNS void AS $$

DECLARE cont int:= (SELECT count(num_eqpo)FROM equipos);
BEGIN

    while cont>0
    LOOP

          INSERT INTO general(equipo,partidos_jug)
          SELECT nom_equipo, COUNT(*) FROM equipos E, partidos as P
          WHERE E.num_eqpo = cont AND (P.num_eqpo_loc=cont OR P.num_eqpo_vis=cont);        

        cont:= cont - 1;
        END LOOP;

RETURN;   
END;   
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I had that function separated in small blocks of code:

```
INSERT INTO general(equipo)
SELECT nom_equipo FROM equipos E
WHERE E.num_eqpo = 1; 

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM partidos as P WHERE (P.num_eqpo_loc=1 OR P.num_eqpo_vis=1)
```

**I want to copy all the information from all the records, not only the first one.**

Using the the function, I get this error:

```
ERROR: the "e.nom_equipo" column must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 2: SELECT nom_equipo, COUNT (*) FROM equipos E, partid ...
               ^
```

Any idea why this error appears in that simple query?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You asked this same question two hours ago and an answer has been given there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The table already exists, so you don't need to create it.  You want to *insert* the rows in `general`:

```
INSERT INTO general(col1, col2, . . .)
    SELECT col1, col2, . ..
    FROM equipos E
    WHERE E.num_eqpo = 2;
```

I'm not quite sure what which columns correspond to which.  You should be explicit about the column lists from each table.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer.

What I did is to store in many variables the values from the Select queries and then I inserted them into the table General thanks to the function developed:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sp_tablageneral () RETURNS void AS $$
DECLARE 
cont int:= (SELECT count(num_eqpo)FROM equipos);
jugados int;
ganados int;
empatados int;
perdidos int;
pts int;
favor int;

BEGIN 
    while cont>0
    LOOP

    jugados:=(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM partidos as P WHERE (P.num_eqpo_loc=cont OR P.num_eqpo_vis=cont));     
    ganados:=(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM partidos AS P WHERE (P.num_eqpo_loc=cont AND P.goles_loc>P.goles_vis OR P.num_eqpo_vis=cont AND P.goles_vis>P.goles_loc));
    empatados:=(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM partidos AS P WHERE (P.num_eqpo_loc=cont AND P.goles_loc=P.goles_vis OR P.num_eqpo_vis=cont AND P.goles_loc=P.goles_vis));
    perdidos:=(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM partidos as P WHERE ( (P.num_eqpo_loc=cont AND P.goles_loc<P.goles_vis) OR (P.num_eqpo_vis=cont AND P.goles_loc>P.goles_vis)));
    pts:=empatados*1 + ganados*3;
    favor:=(SELECT SUM(goles_loc) FROM partidos as P WHERE P.num_eqpo_loc=cont + (SELECT SUM(goles_vis) FROM partidos as P WHERE P.num_eqpo_vis=cont));

    INSERT INTO general(equipo,partidos_jug,partidos_gana,partidos_emp,partidos_perd,puntos,goles_favor)
    SELECT nom_equipo,jugados,ganados,empatados,perdidos,pts,favor FROM equipos E
    WHERE E.num_eqpo = cont;        

    cont:= cont - 1;
    END LOOP;

RETURN;   
END;   
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

[image: Evidencia]